# Using Android wear API and PocketSphinx

Tags: android, audio, record, wear-os, pocketsphinx

After having developed a voice recognition system on my handled device using the [PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) library, I am trying to integrate voice recognition on my android wear device by recording an audio file on the watch and have it sent to my phone for processing.

Here are a few questions regarding this:

1. The process I'm trying to do is: Record an audio file on the watch, sync it onto the phone, have the phone recognize the recorded audio into text (using PocketSphinx) and then send that text back to the watch. Is this doable? if yes, which class can I use to record on android wear? (I have found this link [Send data and wait for the answers with the Wearable Data Layer API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477449/send-data-and-wait-for-the-answers-with-the-wearable-data-layer-api) but it did not help a lot).
2. Is it possible to use external libraries on android wear? (Similar to the ones used on handled devices) (For example: PocketSphinx, Apertium, etc.)
3. Which Android APIs are supported on Android wear other than the ones mentioned below: [Android Wear API](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages-wearable-support.html)

   android.support.wearable
    android.support.wearable.activity
    android.support.wearable.companion
    android.support.wearable.input 
    android.support.wearable.media
    android.support.wearable.provider
    android.support.wearable.view
    android.support.wearable.watchface

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Q.1) Yes what you want to achieve is possible using the `AudioRecord` class. Take a look at the following post for information on recording audio in an Android Wear app.

[How to record audio on android wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321405/how-to-record-audio-on-android-wear)

(Q.2) You can use any external libraries in the same manner as a regular Android app, for example including them using gradle, or importing an AAR or JAR, or even .so library.

(Q.3) In addition to the specific Android Wear API's all the usual Android API's are available to use in an Android Wear app.